# Canvas won't appear in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, chart.js

I have a service where I am getting the ID of the canvas. But when I checked the page it is empty. Can anyone help?
html:

```
<canvas id="{{anID}}" width="900" height="400"></canvas>
```

Inside my service:

```
link: function (scope){
var canvas = document.getElementById(scope.anID);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: Maybe the page looks empty because you are not showing anything in your canvas

Answer (score 0):

```
link: function (scope,element, attrs){
var canvas = element.attrs('id');
```

What about this way of getting ID.

Comment: I get element.attrs is not a function in the console.Idk why (sorry complete noob here)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491344/html-graph-wont-render-with-char-js-v2-0-inside-a-ng-repeat